# JQM: JavaScript doesn't run on page load following DELETE request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, jquery-mobile

When using jQuery Mobile, (how) can I force JavaScript to run following a DELETE request and subsequent page load?

I'm using Devise along with JQM and Rails. When a user signs out (a delete request), Javascript doesn't run on the page that the now-logged-out user is sent to. After Googling, I've found that jQuery Mobile ignores `data-ajax=false` when `data-method=delete`.

https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/issues/189
https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/2103

It doesn't seem like progress has been made on this issue. My goal is for the home page to load nicely when a user logs out; I don't care whether it's via `data-ajax=false` or some other approach. Even something clunky/expensive would be fine for now, since I don't expect users to actually sign out very often.

Does anyone know of a workaround?

I've tried both of the following links. Both have the same result.

```
<li><%= link_to "SIGN OUT", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete, :rel => "external" %></li>
<li><a data-method="delete" rel="external" href="/users/sign_out" class="ui-link" data-ajax="false">SIGN OUT</a></li>
```

No matter what I try, the JavaScript does not run. Also perhaps of relevance, the URL bar reads `http://localhost:3000/users/sign_out` after the user is logged out and the home page is displayed. I don't so much mind the URL (though that is not ideal); but I really need the JavaScript to run. In all other links, I accomplish this by setting `data-ajax=false` or `:rel => external`; only with delete requests is this an issue.

**EDIT:** My own workaround, inspired by [@fortuity](https://github.com/fortuity)'s comment on [this discussion](https://github.com/RailsApps/rails3-mongoid-devise/issues/4). In `config/initializers/devise.rb`, I set `config.sign_out_via = :get`. Now, the sign out request is GET, and everything (JS-wise) works.

I am not counting this as an answer because I still don't know if/how to do the same with a DELETE request. Also, I am wondering if there is a reason why I should not use this workaround, and would appreciate any ideas on that.